# How to select classes that are not nested? CSS

Tags: css, css-selectors

Example:

```
<div class="one">
</div>
<div class="two">
</div>
```

Let's say I want to change the background color of `.two` when I `:hover` over `.one`, is it possible to do that kind of selection?

Comment: What if they're not adjacent though? Is there a way to do that with css?

Comment: if they're adjacent, yes; if they're siblings, yes (see my answer). if they're further apart than that, possibly, but probably not. But if you show us the actual case you want to select rather than a hypothetical case, we might be able to give you a more precise answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If they're next to each other (as you've shown them), then you can use the adjacent (`+`) selector:

```
.one:hover+.two { ... }
```

If they're a bit further away, but still siblings - ie at the same level in the DOM tree - then you can use the sibling (`~`) selector:

```
.one:hover~.two { ... }
```

If they're further apart than that, then you may struggle -- CSS doesn't make it easy at the moment.

Comment: Thank you. Can't wait for variable introduction in CSS4

Comment: even the CSS level 4 selectors might not make it easy in all cases for selecting one arbitrary element based on the hover of another; you'll still need some kind of connection between them. And in any case, even when the new selectors are formalised, we'll still need to wait for widespread browser support before we can actually use them. It'll be a while.

Comment: Both `+` and `~` are sibling combinators - one of them is restricted to adjacent siblings, as you state.

Answer (score 5):

*Let's say I want to change the background color of .two when I :hover over .one, is it possible to do that kind of selection?*

Yes, one option is to use

```
.one:hover + .two {
background: olive; /*  + will select an immediate sibling */
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/N6peE/1/

*That would only work if .two is adjacent to .one, so what if they're not adjacent to one another?*

You would just use the [general sibling combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#general-sibling-combinators), `~`

```
.one:hover ~ .two {
background: olive; 
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/N6peE/2/

Comment: Also note that for both `+` and `~` selectors, they can only apply to downstream siblings (i.e. siblings that appear after the first selector) ;)

Comment: @Terry: "downstream siblings" - I like that term!

Comment: That coming from a biologist background - we use that term a lot :P

Answer (score 2):

```
.one:hover + .two{
 background-color: red;
 }
```

This works only when `.two` is appears after `.one` in your source